# Rxjava2, Retrofit2, download image as byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, retrofit, rx-java2

I try to download several image from url address. After i decode byte[] to bitmap and set it to ImageView. This code works perfect.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(imageUrl)
                            .build();

                    new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            try {
                                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                int current;
                                while ((current = response.body().byteStream().read()) != -1) {
                                    outputStream.write((byte) current);
                                }
                                byte[] array = outputStream.toByteArray();
                                ..........
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

But if i use rxjava2, and retrofit2 it doesn't work out. Byte array come out with many 0 values.

```
public interface ImageApi {

@GET
Observable<ResponseBody> requestImage(@Url String utl);}



Observable(imageUrl()).subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(@NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) {
                            try {
                                if (responseBody != null && responseBody.bytes() != null) {
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    int current;
                                    while ((current = responseBody.byteStream().read()) != -1) {
                                        outputStream.write((byte) current);
                                    }
                                    byte[] array = outputStream.toByteArray(); 
                                }
                        }
```

What i doing wrong ? What difference between OkHttpClient request and Retrofit2 ?

p.s. i don't need to use Glide or Picasso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`responseBody.bytes() != null` - The call to `bytes()` reads the entire stream and then closes the response. Trying to access `responseBody.byteStream()` afterwards always returns a closed stream.

The correct code would be:

```
byte[] array = responseBody.bytes();
```

Since `responseBody` cannot be null (RxJava2 forbids it) and `bytes()` always returns a value or throws an exception.